# How can I make a cylindrical outline to a mesh (2.9)

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am modeling a cello in blender 2.9, and I have finished modeling the basic shape of the cello (see image below)
[image]
However, to make it more realistic I would like to add a slight 3d outline to the mesh like on a real cello.  (example seen below)
[image]
As shown in the example above I would like my cello to have a sort of cylindrical outline around the whole side of the mesh.  I know I could just make a cylinder and start extruding it along the edges, but that would be tiresome and take forever.  Does anyone know of a faster way to go about this?  Any help will be appreciated! :)  (PS, I will leave my file below for anyone who needs it)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to start with your base shape (this is an obviously simplified version):

[image: Base1]

Use insets and/or edge loops to give a "seam" to your edges.

[image: Base2]

Select the "seam edges", right-click and select "Extrude Faces Along Normals" and drag the mouse to bring out the edges to your desired depth. You may also want to check "offset even" in the operator panel in the bottom left corner.

[image: Base3]

Once you have the desired width/depth to your "Seams", add a Subdivision Surface Modifier to round them out. Don't forget to shade smooth.

[image: Base4]

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great!